# Could not launch “Runner” Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain Code: 3

Tags: xcode

Could not launch “Runner”
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: failed to get the task for process 1189
User Info
DVTRadarComponentKey = 855031;
RawLLDBErrorMessage = "failed to get the task for process 1189";

Comment: I have the same issue! Not found a solution yet...

Answer (score 10):

I resolved this error by Trusting my developer account on the iPhone. This particular setting can be found at.

**Settings > General > Device Management**

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in Code signing. Your App is signed with wrong provisioning profile and Xcode isn't allowed to attach debugger to app. For example if you wanna to attach debugger to app that's is signed with AdHoc provisioning profile, you can install&run your app on your device but you can't debug it (attach debugger). If you wanna to attach debugger to your app, you need to use App signed with Development provisioning profile. Check your Signing setting for your project and be sure you are using development Provisioning profile to signing the app.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the other are wrong

Answer (score 3):

run the following command in terminal

**sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable**

ref :- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120282

Answer (score 2):

Enabling WiFi/Cellular on my iPhone fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Unchecking **Debug executable** helped me

Edit Scheme -> Run -> Debug executable

[image]